# Java Unit Test Mock, target class new() method requires depencies mock

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, dependencies

I want to test `A` class.

In A class constructor method, a private final dependency `d` is created. I want to mock `d`. Here is the code

```java
public class A {
    public A () throws FileNotFoundException {}
    private final D d = new D();
}

public class D { 
    public D () throws FileNotFoundException {
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("filePath"));
        // other code...
    }
}
```

Since the filePath is a special path fitting in the docker config, me and my mentor decided to use MOCK to return a `d` to test `A` class.

I did not know how to mock this situation.  Previously, I did use `FieldSetter` in `Mockito` to solve simple cases.

Comment: What are you trying to test, exactly? Also, note this is a good argument for dependency injection (which is just a fancy way to say give the constructors parameters, or create constructor overloads with the parameters, so that you can pass "mock" objects at test time but "real" objects in deployment).

Comment: @Slaw `A` is actually a `Messagehandler`, which is used to execute messages from kafka. `D` is `LocalJsonContractDescriptionProvider` for loading blockchain contract description file `contract.json`. I want to test my `A` methods work as expected.

For constructor, `A` does not have a constructor to pass `D` into `A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option would be to declare `D` as a constructor argument. This is also called dependency injection and can be useful for testing. Additionally, you can still have a constructor without any arguments:

```
public class A {
    public A (D d) throws FileNotFoundException {
        this.d = d;
    }
    public A () throws FileNotFoundException {
        this(new D());
    }

    private final D d;
} 

@Test
void test() {
    D mock = mock(D.class);
    A tested = new A(mock);
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can test this code even more elegantly, without any mocks. To do so, we need to apply the same technique to `D` and use dependency injection for passing a `Reader`:

```
public class D { 
    public D () throws FileNotFoundException {
        this(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("filePath")));
    }
    public D (Reader reader) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // other code...
    }
}
```

Since `Reader` is an interface, we can use different implementations for it, inside the test. For instance, we can use a `StringReader`:

```
@Test
void test() {
    D d = new D(new StringReader("my test file content"));
    A tested = new A(d);
    // ...
}
```